# iPhone SDK: Problems after downgrading from Xcode4 to Xcode3

Tags: iphone, sdk, xamarin.ios, xcode3to4

[Using MonoTouch to build iOS]

We recently upgraded from Xcode3 to Xcode4 but then decided to downgrade as the Interface builder wasn't working yet with MonoTouch.

After running the uninstall for Xcode, we installed 3.2.6.

When we build and submit the app, Apple now says, "Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK"

It was accepting though a few days ago. We have tried many options/reinstalls etc, but all to no effect.

Is there a way to determine what MonoTouch is using and what it is applying to the build to make Apple think the SDK version is wrong?

Comment: What version of the SDK is MonoTouch building against? Note that the SDK version is not the same as the Xcode version.

Comment: The Xcode 3.2.6 build from develop.apple.com

Comment: Not the Xcode version, the iOS SDK version. MonoTouch is building against a version of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current MonoDevelop.  An update should be out soon.

Comment: Thank you. I spent a long time last night reading and trying to pry under the covers. Lots of good learning.

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed the keys required in the application manifest in iOS SDK 4.3.1. We've released a new MonoDevelop build to track this.